# Using IF/ELSE in Postman Test scripts

Tags: javascript, if-statement, postman-testcase

I am using Postman in order to test, But I am stuck on using if/else in the scripts.

My goal is to test if a property is visible in the response body. if the property is not there, I want postman to expect it be empty. and move on to the next test. The properties are nested in an array.

This is what I came up with so far.:

```js
//Test of correct sub properties rijbewijs zijn meegestuurd
pm.test("Test if correct sub properties rijbewijs are sent", () => {
    if (pm.expect(matchesVacatures.rijbewijs).to.be.empty);
    else { pm.expect(matchesRijbewijs).to.have.property('codeSoortRijbewijs');}  
});
```

However, the test always "fails" if the array is not empty.
How do I go about this, it might be something small that have I placed incorrectly in the test, but I cant quite figure it out.

Comment: Why not use `if (!pm.expect(matchesVacatures.rijbewijs).to.be.empty) pm.expect(matchesRijbewijs).to.have.property('codeSoortRijbewijs')` instead of having a semicolon

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however the ! seems to be ignored by Postman and it yields the same results.

Comment: I did not expect it to fix your issue, just makes better code

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
pm.test("Test if correct sub properties rijbewijs are sent", () => {
    if ((matchesVacatures.rijbewijs).length !== 0)
    {pm.expect(matchesVacatures.rijbewijs[0]).to.have.property('codeSoortRijbewijs');}
```